# session_get_cookie_params() doesn't work

Tags: php, cookies

I have a code snippet in application whose domain is **http://localhost/xyz/**

I am creating a cookie using a snippet

```
$cookie_name = "AMCV_98DC73AE52E13F1E0A490D4C@!#$%&~|AdobeOrg";
$cookie_value = "kuchbhi";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

right after this I am trying to execute `session_get_cookie_params()`to get the domain details of the cookie created above using below code snippet

```
$cookieInfo = session_get_cookie_params();
echo $cookieInfo['domain'];
```

But still I do not get any domain name, even on printing the array of $cookieInfo, I get empty array.

Please suggest how exactly does the function session_get_cookie_params() works..

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. If `session_get_cookie_params()` really returns an empty string you must have hit a strange platform bug because it works even in non-HTTP environment (I admit I had to test it). Here's the simplest [fiddle](http://3v4l.org/EEjP1). But that's a function to read some PHP configuration about sessions—how does that relate to your previous code?

Answer (score 2):

Function session_get_cookie_params() is based on a bunch of php.ini file values:

```
session.cookie_lifetime
session.cookie_path
session.cookie_domain
session.cookie_secure
session.cookie_httponly
```

You can set values in your php.ini file, or you can override those values at the start of your script with:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'www.example.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests and [the manual](http://php.net/session_get_cookie_params) explicits, this function gathers info about **session** cookies:

> **session**_get_cookie_params — Get the **session** cookie
>
> Gets the session cookie parameters.
>   [...]
>   Returns an array with the current session cookie information

In other works, it's a fancy wrapper to read some PHP settings in one line, rather than issuing [five calls to `ini_get()`](http://php.net/session_get_cookie_params#80393).

I suspect you are confusing cookies and sessions and possibly think they're synonyms. They aren't: cookies are a client side storage and sessions are a server-side storage. PHP happens to allow (and encourage) the use of cookies in order to transmit the session ID that tells the server-side storage who you are, but that's all. Think of the session cookie as the magnetic card that opens your office: that doesn't make your MasterCard has anything to do with doors.

If your question is "how do I get back my cookie parameters" the answer is that you can't. Open your browser's developer tools and you'll see that the browser never sends that information:

[image: Firebug: Net pane]

Comment: it doesn't work either, before creating the cookie, I wrote the session_start();

Comment: @OMTheEternity - I think I didn't make myself clear so I've fixed some confusing information and expanded the answer.

Comment: We can only read the [cookie name and value](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php).